# How do I write this iterated product for $e$ in big-pi notation?

Tags: notation

From [this paper](https://watermark.silverchair.com/11-2-229.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAkUwggJBBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggIyMIICLgIBADCCAicGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMDq4PKSDEw-l1TigtAgEQgIIB-JPC9H7h7HFwUJh-fj-8NT_0i3mocya8E8n8x4ljuEtElL9czlO0TdX0Xd-49z_MY_7ZMGIC27TxZtBpulf6e-4y7CJjJ62lCccXjDrIBZWxErBuBkO0mSDIa8n0WZsFkjraCrwIBjnO2uB896W1rUq57ZBrpvBzeSypIV9OBNJtHj53_TLwxPNEzht-hKGCNWFZKhswHvJT1vp2n4AzOZKrwtrIGN9wi0feCRN1FWmm95AgvQ-4M0XU6cBpWw2aXnGc3MXZo0tjpDAcVvTU8ERWqoGLG0TnUrxxynjaz8MPcnGiKdOwLHuZaCivUX3O1ywN7jMu6Wnqxf8lKXG1_4jtiidVU9l5Z3STOdzXyVS8guGbEBiMyI6kaHlEP27eT8Tgmg6TB0vEMpAjunTlLS_H48lLmyPKXD9dZnPShUZ4-Gqigq-SLH_oRTAeiYeP7unvXKgmLksVsratvOZmvxWz7nRmqDslZqBk59enejdgFFZwOtyml1Av5ADAXv_-nxJqnfohdpF5MVzxvi0Kx5d56D4LFAQcRp4fvSycij6mtVCkao4yfoej5jR6iqQT4UACEgdLa_fyCvXgvpRlkBvUEGzbIlOfPm9jlfxSWy0o1HaEI278HdCV-Gd2FStjmv8_ytC2Rc591AQcCAe93JBHqwGZCubtsw).

> Examination of the regrouped series for $e$, given below, shows what is the well-known method of rewriting polynomials in a slightly different guise:
>
> $$1 + 1\left(1 + \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac13\left(...\left(1 + \frac1n\right)...\right)\right)\right)$$

How do I rewrite this as a function of $n$ in big-pi notation?

Comment: I don't see a simple way of writing that in a big pi notation. There are sums involved which make it so that it is quite difficult to find $a_i$ such that that expression will equal to product of $a_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to write this using $\prod$ notation, simply because it can't be broken up into a single, long product. All those multiplications that happen happen *inside* other factors, not *next to* other factors.

However, if you expand the parentheses, you can make it into a combined form with
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\left(\prod_{k = 1}^n\frac1k\right)
$$
which is basically just another way of writing the very standard $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac1{n!}$.

Comment: How about $\ln\left(\prod_{n=0}^\infty e^{1/n!}\right)$?

Comment: @BarryCipra Of course, any sum can be translated into a logarithm of a product. So, sure, that would work.